# Post request in VueJs with undefined response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am a beginner in VueJs and Expressjs. I am trying to make frontend side by Vuejs and backend by ExpressJs. I send a post request to the backend (expressJs) and :

1- Response is undefined
2- At the same time I can see 2 requests in chrome development tools. One is Option and another one is Post.
3- With postman there is no problem at all.

[image]

Here is the code of app.js in express

```js
console.log('Server is running')

const express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    morgan = require('morgan');

app = new express();

//Setup middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({
        message: `Hello ${req.body.email}! your user was registered!`
    })
});

app.listen(8081);
```

And here is the code in VueJs :

```js
// Api Setting

import axios from 'axios'

export const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8081`
  });



// AuthenticationService

import { HTTP } from '../services/Api'

export default {

  register(credentials) {
     HTTP.post('register', credentials);
  }
}



// Register Component 
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
   
   async register() {
        const response = await AuthenticationService.register({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      });

      console.log(response);  // the value is undefined
    }
  }
};
```

I really don't know what I missed here that I get an undefined response and 2 requests at the same time. I appreciate any hint.

Whole code on github repo  : [here](https://github.com/peymannj/VueApp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. `Authentication.register` is not returning anything or more specifically a `Promise` which should be used to populate `const response` in the `await` call.

Try returning something like so: `return HTTP.post('register', credentials);` inside `register`.

For this to work though, `HTTP.post('register', credentials)` should also return something.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know why we have to requests ( option, post ) ? Is it something normal ?

Answer (score 1):

I use JSON.stringify to send the data, you are sending the objects directly, so

```
register(credentials) {
    HTTP.post('register', credentials);
}
```

becomes

```
register(credentials) {
    HTTP.post('register', JSON.stringify(credentials));
}
```

Comment: also, I haven't got the baseurl part... don't know if that has any effect. My code is like
`axios.post('http://example.com/bla',JSON.stringify(data)).then(`

Comment: Regarding your question about post/and option... Normally, I would say that axios does not send anything unless you code it. However, there could be some default settings that require an option to be sent before the post is launched. Have a look at the request body in dev tools and see what option has as body